# Show image from controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I am displaying an image in view using
`<%= image_tag(@staff.attachment_url(@staff.image), alt: "No image", width: "100px", height: "100px") %>` which is working fine.

Here `attachment_url` is method for creating dynamic url every time you open the image
`i.e. staff_profiles/images/b64f8b457dddf968712401bf07a8d08ba7f1ce3a326598ec2144f1c995309e06`
and also this image is valid for 30 second only and after 30 second when you refresh or open the same url it will show `Access denied`.

Everything here is working fine.

Like this image i have other attachments to download/view with download link. when any user open page this attachment_url calls at the time of page load / show method  but after 30 seconds this download link expires and  when user click on the link it shows `Access Denied`. I want to call the `attachment_url` when user click on download link after 1 minute or 5 minutes or 10 minutes of page load.

So I need to open the image or create download link url from controller, Not like mentioned above and also want to use the method given above `attachment_url` which will help to create url dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any additional details you could add?  Could you explain a little about what you mean by "open the image from controller"?  And also _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: Could this be implemented as a `redirect_to <temporary_url>`?

Comment: If you want images to be public (e.g. is the image stored in AWS?) then you could consider changing the bucket permissions to "public".

Comment: This is the motive to PREVENT to do the image or link as public.

Comment: Create `ImageController` with a `show` method which redirects to attachment_url. You can put all sort of authorisation on that action. image tags do follow redirects the last time I've checked (however would be good to check it in various browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def attachment_link
  # logic to build dynamic URL
  image_url = @staff.attachment_url(@staff.image)
  redirect_to image_url
end
```

In Controller above works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To display an image from a controller's action. You can use [send_file](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionController/Streaming/send_file).

```rb
# in your controller

  def attachment_link
      # logic to build dynamic URL
      image_url = @staff.attachment_url(@staff.image)

      # type: add the correct file content type
      # disposition: 'inline' will display file in browser
      send_file image_url, type: "image/png", disposition: "inline"
  end
```

Comment: I had tried this but i am getting error `Cannot read file https://xxxx-development.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com.....`
`redirect_to image_url ` is working for me
Thanks